# Can I be "friendfully yours"

Tags: etymology, adverbs, pragmatics

**friendly (advs). : Used to mean 'in a friendly manner.**

> I am wondering if "friendfully"  was/is in standard usage and would
>   I sound primitive or ungrammatical if I dare write "friendfully yours"
>   in an e-mail signature.

Comment: What did you find in a dictionary?

Comment: Far from standard/formal usage, but might in fact be a truly "friendly" signoff for someone who is an "intimate" (in the non-sexual meaning of the term).  I would not suggest it as a standard email signature, however.

Comment: You can use the more common version, "Your Friend,"

Comment: With [only 36 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22friendfully%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books (mostly centuries old), it would be a *frightfully* odd thing to write in an email today. There are apparently [over 10,000 instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22friendlily%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) of ***friendlily***, but I can't say that seems any better to me.

Comment: Try *cordially* instead. Your correspondents will appreciate it.

Comment: Or _Affectionately_ ...

Comment: I got my answer, Instead of being fanciful it/I would appear "frightfully odd".  Thankyou,@FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, "friendfully" is a word, though it is "rare after the 16th century". While friendly can also sometimes be used as an adverb,

> friendly yours

will probably sound incoherent or uneducated here.  You can also form an adverb from friendly by applying the common "-ly" suffix to form "friendlily", which may sound more appropriate:

> friendlily yours

Some links you may find useful:

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74658?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=SYRyLe& ("friendly", adj. and n.)

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/322863?isAdvanced=false&result=2&rskey=SYRyLe& ("friendly", adv.)

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74656?redirectedFrom=friendlily& ("friendlily", adv.)

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/320283?redirectedFrom=friendfully& ("friendfully, adv.)

Comment: So 'Friendfully thine' works better?

Comment: I suppose it would, although "thou" was the informal 2nd person pronoun when it was in common use, so perhaps not.